# How can I use multiple select forms as a password input?

Tags: javascript, html, web, passwords

I'm currently creating a puzzle website and one of the pages requires the user to input all of their clues into the page via select forms, press submit, and if all of the clues are correct they can progress.

I'm having an issue with having multiple passwords however. It doesn't matter what the user inputs for the first 4 clues, as long as the final 5th clue is correct it claims it's correct.

I've tried searching quite a few terms which could link to this, but I've had no luck. I'm not the greatest with Javascript (In fact I'm super rusty at it!) so hopefully it's just me being an idiot and not a "This can't be done" case.

Here is a stripped down version of the password select form:

```
 <body>
        <div>
            <table style="width: 100%;">
                <tr>
                    <td><select id="pswd1" name="pswd1" style="width: 100%;">
                        <option value="1">
                            1
                        </option>
                        <option value="2">
                            2
                        </option>
                        <option value="3">
                            3
                        </option>
                        <option value="4">
                            4
                        </option>
                        <option value="5">
                            5
                        </option>
                    </select></td>
                    <td><select id="pswd2" name="pswd2" style="width: 100%;">
                        <option value="1">
                            1
                        </option>
                        <option value="2">
                            2
                        </option>
                        <option value="3">
                            3
                        </option>
                        <option value="4">
                            4
                        </option>
                        <option value="5">
                            5
                        </option>
                    </select></td>
                    <td><select id="pswd3" name="pswd3" style="width: 100%;">
                        <option value="1">
                            1
                        </option>
                        <option value="2">
                            2
                        </option>
                        <option value="3">
                            3
                        </option>
                        <option value="4">
                            4
                        </option>
                        <option value="5">
                            5
                        </option>
                    </select></td>
                    <td><select id="pswd4" name="pswd4" style="width: 100%;">
                        <option value="1">
                            1
                        </option>
                        <option value="2">
                            2
                        </option>
                        <option value="3">
                            3
                        </option>
                        <option value="4">
                            4
                        </option>
                        <option value="5">
                            5
                        </option>
                    </select></td>
                    <td><select id="pswd5" name="pswd5" style="width: 100%;">
                        <option value="1">
                            1
                        </option>
                        <option value="2">
                            2
                        </option>
                        <option value="3">
                            3
                        </option>
                        <option value="4">
                            4
                        </option>
                        <option value="5">
                            5
                        </option>
                    </select></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <table style="width: 100%; text-align: center;">
                <tr>
                    <td><input onclick="checkPswd();" type="button" value="Submit"></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
           function checkPswd() {

               var confirmPassword = "1";
               var password = document.getElementById("pswd1").value;

               var confirmPassword = "2";
               var password = document.getElementById("pswd2").value;

               var confirmPassword = "3";
               var password = document.getElementById("pswd3").value;

               var confirmPassword = "4";
               var password = document.getElementById("pswd4").value;

               var confirmPassword = "5";
               var password = document.getElementById("pswd5").value;

               if (password == confirmPassword) {
                    window.location="https://www.youtube.com/";
               }
               else{
                   alert("Try again");
               }
           }
        </script>
    </body>
```

Any help would be massively appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

The problem u have is that u set the password variable at the end equal to the fifth one.
Try replace the following instead of this :

ur code :
     function checkPswd() {

```
               var confirmPassword = "YES";
               var password = document.getElementById("pswd1").value;

               var confirmPassword = "YES";
               var password = document.getElementById("pswd2").value;

               var confirmPassword = "YES";
               var password = document.getElementById("pswd3").value;

               var confirmPassword = "YES";
               var password = document.getElementById("pswd4").value;

               var confirmPassword = "YES";
               var password = document.getElementById("pswd5").value;

               if (password == confirmPassword) {
                    window.location="https://www.youtube.com/";
               }
               else{
                   alert("Try again");
               }
           }
```

replace with :

```
function checkPswd() {
    var confirmPassword = "YES";    

    var pass1 = document.getElementById("pswd1").value;
    var pass2 = document.getElementById("pswd2").value;
    var pass3 = document.getElementById("pswd3").value;
    var pass4 = document.getElementById("pswd4").value;
    var pass5 = document.getElementById("pswd5").value;

           if (pass1 == confirmPassword && pass2 == confirmPassword && pass3 == confirmPassword && pass4 == confirmPassword && pass5 == confirmPassword) {
                window.location="https://www.youtube.com/";
           }
           else{
               alert("Try again");
           }
       }
```

in fact u were just checking the fifth not all of them... Hope it help

Comment: That fixed the problem! Thankyou very much.

I have a follow up question, say I wanted to get a bit more complex with this, and have each password a different word. What would I need to change in your code to achieve this?

Comment: just replace ur words with confirmPasswords in if (pass1 == confirmPassword && pass2 == confirmPassword && pass3 == confirmPassword && pass4 == confirmPassword && pass5 == confirmPassword)